# Grid data cannot be displayed in jqgrid if data has escaped single quote

Tags: jqgrid

Returned JSON data:

```
{
    "page": "1",
    "total": 1,
    "records": "1",
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "10142",
            "cell": [
                "10142",
                "Hello",
                "c:\\goodies\'",
                "singlequoteissue" 
            ] 
        } 
    ]
}
```

String with problem (i.e. \' at the end)

```
"c:\\goodies\'"
```

jqgrid works fine without the single quote ...

Thanks in advance.

Martin

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data which use receive from the server are wrong. You can validate any JSON data [here](http://www.jsonlint.com/). On the http://www.json.org/ is described which characters must be escaped (only " and ) and which can be escaped with the backslash. The ' character is in no from the lists. So you data should be fixed to

```
{
    "page": "1",
    "total": 1,
    "records": "1",
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "10142",
            "cell": [
                "10142",
                "Hello",
                "c:\\goodies'",
                "singlequoteissue" 
            ] 
        } 
    ]
}
```

I recommend you don't implement manual JSON serialization on the server and use some standard function (or library). In the case you will not have such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Problem found, the JSON string is not valid should be "c:\goodies'" instead